# How do you add classes to children of multiple parents?

Tags: javascript, html

Using JS, I would like to be able to add a class to children of multiple parents.

```html
<div id="artwork">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="flex_container">
            <div class="box artwork_flex">
                <h2>ARTWORK</h2>
                <h3>Example 1</h3>
                <p>Nullam id posuere magna. Praesent eu bibendum augue, ac tempor leo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box image_flex">
                <img src="images/example_1.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex_container">
            <div class="box artwork_flex">
                <h3>Example 2</h3>
                <p>Nullam id posuere magna. Praesent eu bibendum augue, ac tempor leo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box image_flex">
                <img src="images/example_2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex_container">
            <div class="box artwork_flex">
                <h3>Example 3</h3>
                <p>Nullam id posuere magna. Praesent eu bibendum augue, ac tempor leo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box image_flex">
                <img src="images/example_3.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to remove the class `artwork_flex` and replace it with `artwork_flex_op` in all of the **odd** `flex container`s (this needs to be dynamic and work with more/less `flex_container`s than the three that are currently there).

Does anyone know how to do this in JavaScript? Thank you in advance.

Comment: so you want to replace the word ```artwork_flex``` with ```artwork_flex_op``` why do you need a loop for it?

Comment: @seriously because there are multiple of them, although I guess looking back on it now there are other ways of doing it - I'm a new developer in JS so only know a small range of methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DOMTokenList.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace) and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). The expression `index % 2 != 0` tells use whether the element currently being looped through is even or odd.

In the demo below, the div with a red background color has the `artwork_flex_op` class.

```js
var flexContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.flex_container');
flexContainers.forEach((e, i) => {
  if (i % 2 != 0) {
    e.querySelector('.artwork_flex').classList.replace('artwork_flex', 'artwork_flex_op');
  }
})
```

```css
.artwork_flex_op {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="artwork">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex_container">
      <div class="box artwork_flex">
        <h2>ARTWORK</h2>
        <h3>Example 1</h3>
        <p>Nullam id posuere magna. Praesent eu bibendum augue, ac tempor leo.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box image_flex">
        <img src="images/example_1.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex_container">
      <div class="box artwork_flex">
        <h3>Example 2</h3>
        <p>Nullam id posuere magna. Praesent eu bibendum augue, ac tempor leo.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box image_flex">
        <img src="images/example_2.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex_container">
      <div class="box artwork_flex">
        <h3>Example 3</h3>
        <p>Nullam id posuere magna. Praesent eu bibendum augue, ac tempor leo.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box image_flex">
        <img src="images/example_3.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```